# Animating a circle UIImageView to disappear

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

If I have a UIImageView of a circle, how could Core Animation make it disappear like in this question?

[How to use CoreAnimation to animate a circle like a clock countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895244/how-to-use-coreanimation-to-animate-a-circle-like-a-clock-countdown)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `CAShapeLayer`.  Set its `path` to your “clock” shape.  Set it as the layer mask of your image view (e.g. `imageView.layer.mask = shapeLayer`).

Then you can try using a `CAKeyframeAnimation` to animate the shape layer's `path`, but I suspect the results won't be pleasing.  Instead you'll probably want to use a `CADisplayLink` as a timer and update the shape layer's `path` every time it fires.

Comment: You can actually get really good results with a very wide circular path and animating the strokeEnd as in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10651797/608157)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist how would I draw this within a UITableViewCell? Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is known as a "clock wipe" transition.

David is pointing you in the right direction. I have a sample project on Github that shows exactly what you are looking for:

[**iOS Core Animation Demo**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo)

When you run the app, click on the "Mask Animation" button. It does what you're talking about. It shows an image view with a clock wipe, and then hides it again. It would be a simple matter to switch it around to have the image fully visible at first and then animate a clock wipe to hide it.